# Как заменить слэш

Tags: php

Пытаюсь `$var = str_replace('\','/',$var);`
и пишет ошибку

Comment: `$var = str_replace('\\','/',$var); `

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать двойной бэкслэш:

```
$str = str_replace('\\', '/', $str);
```

<sub>Источник: [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806597/replacing-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-with-str-replace-in-php)</sub>.

Comment: Было бы неплохо объяснить, почему двойной слеш. Почему одинарный выдает ошибку.

Comment: Значит источник enSO, а не мануал. Понятно

Answer (score 6):

знак \ - означает экранирование символов - поэтому и выдает ошибку, в данном случае \ - покажет что второй слеш надо расценивать как обычный символ.